# How to store URL param in htaccess variable

Tags: .htaccess

All my URLs can be appended with `?lang=xx` but I don't want to rewrite all my `htaccess` rules, so I would like to catch this parameter and attach when available.

I've tried to save the param to variable `MYLANG` as follows, but doesn't work:

```
SetEnv MYLANG %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-zA-Z]{2})$
```

This is another attempt that didn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-zA-Z]{2})$
SetEnv MYLANG %1
```

And another attempt:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-zA-Z]{2})$
RewriteRule ^ - [env=MYLANG:%1]
```

I can then use the captured variable in the rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /?name=$1&lang=%{ENV:MYLANG} [NC,L]
```

Or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /?name=$1 [NC,L,E=MYLANG]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used it, but it seems to me that's it:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-zA-Z]{2})$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MYLANG:%1]

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /?name=$1&lang=%{ENV:MYLANG} [NC,L]
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, but without the "REDIRECT_" part in the above code. Will mark it as the right answer once corrected.

Comment: Thank you. I know it is added after redirecting. I had a doubt in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Nice idea. Your third attempt:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-zA-Z]{2})$
RewriteRule ^ - [env=MYLANG:%1]
```

Should work fine.